# How to generate the EC2 cerificate

Tags: amazon-ec2

While setting up the EC2 access, it seems I need two files, the private key and ec2 certificate.

```
$ export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=~/.ec2/pk-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem 
$ export EC2_CERT=~/.ec2/cert-HKZYKTAIG2ECMXYIBH3HXV4ZBZQ55CLO.pem
```

However, I did not find anywhere I could download or create the key.

from the documentation:

> The command line tools need access to
>   the private key and X.509 certificate
>   you generated after signing up for the
>   Amazon EC2 service.

I probably missed that, Is it possible to generate it again

Answer (score 0):

When signed in on the AWS website go to Account -> Security Credentials -> X.509 Certificates.

You can generate, download, or upload certificates there.